# how to to sum each rows  in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

how to make the formula effect on the whole sheet.

the format is : get each lines number sum. then substract some numbers.

eg: there are 100 lines records.  how to make the formula effects on each lines?

namely :  `A1+B1+C1+D1+`....equals a number, then using the number-20 -15....

each line using the same way,  thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to give it a more descriptive title than "how to to this in excel?" (sic)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can input a range into `=SUM()` like this:

```
=SUM(A1:X1)
```

This calculates the sum of the 1. line from A to X.
Just copy/paste the formula to ther rows to calculate the some for those.

Comment: thank you,if i don't want to  copy/paste  the formula to those rows to calculate the result, is there a way to get that. namely. not copy/paste too times.

Comment: You can select the whole column by clicking on its header and paste the formula once.

Comment: i am sorry, i don't know how to do it. when i selected all the  column s there still one record i can't selected(eg:A1), and where should i put the formula in?

Comment: Put the formula in one cell where you want it. Copy the formula into your clipboard (CTRL+C), select the column with a click on the column header, and paste the formula back (CTRL+V).

Comment: =SUM(A1:X1) this formula can use only once, when get the second row sum, i should change it into =SUM(B1:X1). IT TOO complicated.

Comment: No, you dont have to change it. It is changed automatically when you copy/paste it. `B1:X1` is wrong anyway, it would be `A2:X2`. But excel takes care of that for you.

Comment: @cularis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1447/discussion-between-zhuanzhou-and-cularis)

Comment: i am very sorry,i can't make it a success. could you give me some screenshots. many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Drag the sum down in corner of cell where cursor becomes `+` sign